# ¿Porque No me encuentra mi sp en sql server a través del exec?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Quiero crear un sp con un simple insert pero my gestor de bd no me lo encuentra una vez ya creado.

Codigo SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  InsertHistory
  @vehiculoId varchar(30),
  @FechaC date,
  @FechaF date,
  @CodigoQR int,
  @FotoE varchar(40),
  @Estatus varchar(20),
  @Dueno varchar(30)
  AS
  begin
INSERT INTO tbHistorico(VehiculoId, FechaCreacion, FechaVigencia, CodigoQR, FotografiaEvidencia, Estatus, Dueño)
VALUES (@vehiculoId, @FechaC , @FechaF , @CodigoQR , @FotoE, @Estatus, @Dueno);
end
GO
```

Después quiero ejecutarlo con `exec` y no me deja, me dice que no encuentra el sp, pero este si existe.

```
exec InsertHistory;
```

Cuando se crea el sp en sql server me lo crea de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si tenga algo que ver con que me ponga `db_datareader` al inicio del sp. Pero no se como evitar que suceda esa situación.

Comment: Buenos dias yo tengo el mismo inconveniente, creo el sp, pero me lo coloca el rojito, al ejecutarlo me lo ejecuta pero si lo mando a ejecutar desde un trigger me da error por que dice que no existe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por defecto en una instalación en MSSQL, el esquema es `[dbo]`. Si el Stored Procedure aparece con un esquema diferente en el explorador, es necesario invocarlo incluyendo el esquema correspondiente. Que tenga `db_datareader` indica que lo estás creando con un usuario que deja todos los objetos por defecto en ese esquema.

Que se cree en dbo o en otro esquema depende de con qué usuario abres la ventana de query en la aplicación de SMSS y qué esquema por defecto tenga ese usuario.

Edito: flxtr tiene razón y olvidé tal vez lo más importante: la forma de ejecutarlo tal cual está quedando creado ahora.

```
EXEC db_datareader.InsertHistory
```

Comment: Coincido con tu respuesta, solo faltaría indicar la forma en que se debería ejecutar: `EXEC db_datareader.InsertHistory`